# Unit testing inheritance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I have a question concerning unit testing. Let's say that I have several classes that inherit behaviour from a parent class. I don't want to test all the child classes for this behaviour. Instead I would test the parent class. However, I should also provide a test proving that the behaviour is available in the child classes. Do you think something like Assert.IsTrue(new ChildClass() is ParentClass) makes sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using a state-of-the-art unit-testing framework, I don't understand the statement

> I don't want to test all the child classes for this behaviour.

Your unit tests (written against an instance of the parent class) should work unchanged if you hand them an instance of a child class, ***provided*** that your child class hasn't overridden some aspect of the parent's behavior in a way that breaks the contract on the inherited methods. And that's exactly what you need to be testing, isn't it?

If you're concerned about the time it takes to run the tests, I'd double-check to make sure that your tests are partitioned such that you can selectively run tests based on what you're actively working on (but still run the full portfolio periodically to catch unintended dependencies.)

Comment: Amen.  This is a very good reason to actually test that the "inheritance works" (ie conforms to the Liskov substitution principle) rather than just verify that child classes are subtypes of the parent class.

Comment: It's not that I'm concerned about the time it takes to run the test. I just want to write the minimum number of tests possible to make rafactoring in the future easier.

Comment: @trendl - If you use NUnit, you could create one unit test for the base class and use the [TestCase] attribute to feed in all child classes you have - that gives you a check as suggested by Joel for all of your subclasses for free.

Comment: There are a few posts around that tell you off for using inheritance on test classes such as http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/

Comment: that said i actually agree with you i think these post see people misusing inheritance so preach about not using it at all rather than saying you should use it correctly

Answer (score 11):

make your tests inherit from a base class test, something [very]roughly like this.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoStuff() { }
    public virtual void DoOtherStuff() { }
}

public class MySubClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override void DoOtherStuff()
    {
        // different to to base
    }
}

public abstract class TestOfBaseClass
{
    protected abstract MyBaseClass classUnderTest { get; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDoStuff()
    {
        classUnderTest.DoStuff();
        Assert.StuffWasDone();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class WhenSubclassDoesStuff : TestOfBaseClass
{
    protected override MyBaseClass classUnderTest
    {
        get { return new MySubClass(); }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShoudDoOtherStuff()
    {
        classUnderTest.DoOtherStuff();
        Assert.OtherStuffDone();
    }
}
```

most of the popular test frameworks will run the test method in the base test when running the subclass tests.

or maybe have a look at something like https://github.com/gregoryyoung/grensesnitt

Comment: This is exactly what we were looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I think that writing a test that inheritance works is a waste of time.  The compiler will check that the base class methods are available if you try to use them, assuming you don't catch with intellisense. I would probably test the behavior in one child class and then only in each child class that modifies the behavior (or some state the behavior depends on).

Comment: `writing a test that inheritance works is a waste of time. The compiler will check...` Issues caught by unit tests and isues caught by the compiler are completely separate. Unit tests require compilation to succeed. `The compiler will check that the base class methods are available if you try to use them` The question isn't about conforming to the base class contract, but rather to confirm that the **behavior** inside the (correctly inherited methods) is consistent.

Comment: `would probably test the behavior in one child class and then only in each child class that modifies the behavior` If you do that, then you will never catch future issues whereby a second child's (previously default) behavior is inadvertently changed.

Answer (score 6):

You wouldn't want to test the type of the object, **unless** it's coming out of an untyped factory method.  Otherwise you're writing a unit test against the C# compiler which is not what you want to do.

Comment: you could argue that having a test that inheritance chains haven't been broken is a valid test. after all you could have class A a that inherits class B which inherits class C and at some point in the futures a dev decides A pointing directly at C would be better with out realising that A is dependent on a data transformation performed by B

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler takes care of that kind of check for you.

If you like you can write something like:

```
ParentClass childClass = new ChildClass()
var testOutput = childClass.ParentMethod();
Assert.IsNotNull(testOutput);
```

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that your Test Structure should reflect your object structure
so if you have Class Car that Inherits from Class Vehicle

then you should have Class TestCar that inherits from Class TestVehicle

By doing this Test car automatically inherits the correct tests for all Vehicle tests this means that if the function is overridden in Car it will most likely break the test highlighting that a Overriden Test is required in Car to support the new behaviour, if the test isn't broken then the override was probably superfluous in the first place

eg

```
class Vehicle
{
    public virtual bool LicenceRequired
    {
        get{throw new NotImplmentedException()
    }
}
class Bicycle:Vehicle
{
    public override bool LicenceRequired
    {
        get{return false;}
    }
}
class Car:Vehicle
{
    public override bool LicenceRequired
    {
        get{return true;}
    }
}
class TestVehicle
{
    public virtual Void LicenceRequiredTest()
    {
        Try
        {
            LicenceRequired
            Assert.Fail();
        }
        Catch(){}
    }
}
class TestBicycle:TestVehicle
{
    public override void LicenceRequiredTest()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(LicenceRequired);
    }
}
class TestCar:TestVehicle
{
    public override void LicenceRequiredTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(LicenceRequired);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Inheritance should only be used when testing inherited objects, not just because you want to do the same test on 10 unrelated objects. if you want to do that I'd suggest a static helper class

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use to test the *behavior* of the base class:

1. Create a stub implementation of the base class, and unit test the stub.  Only test the public methods.  It's pointless to test your private and protected methods, since those will be consumed by public methods that you should test in your subclasses.  This approach will not enforce that your implementations of the base class hasn't shadowed behavior incorrectly.
2. Create test superclass for your unit tests that exercises the base class methods.  Whenever you're testing a subclass of your base class, have your test class inherit from your test superclass.  This approach ensures that you haven't changed the behavior of the base class inadvertently, but limits the flexability of your test.

Don't bother to verify that inheritance actually works (the whole `Assert.IsTrue(new ChildClass() is ParentClass)` thing).  You should only test behavior.  This is a structural feature of the .Net framework (inheritance), and you should trust that it works, otherwise you'll find yourself in a downward spiral of checking framework features.

Comment: the definition of unit testing is you test the smallest possible component so single methods and properties that means that you should always test your sub calls seperately